# In Passengers, how would it have been possible for anyone to return?

Tags: passengers

In *Passengers*, we are told that they are unable to reenter hibernation BUT we are also told that

> Aurora was planning to spend one year on Homestead II before going back to earth with the ship.

This is presumably the same journey in reverse and therefore the crew and all returning passengers would have needed to re-enter hibernation.

Homestead II is a new colony, therefore the means to re-enter hibernation MUST be carried on the ship with them - both the instructions and the material (drugs, equipment etc).

My question is:

> How do we resolve this - Jim and Aurora cannot reenter hibernation now, but when the ship arrives they will be able to put the whole crew back under after only a year.

It seems like a massive plot hole to me?

Comment: Nice one. Probably we are supposed to assume, that there are certain requirements that can only be fulfilled by going planetside, maybe you must breath unrecycled air for at least a whole year, before going under again won't kill you or some similar reason, which is why Aurora opted to stay a year.

Comment: Most (if not all) of the information in your question isn't really spoilery, so I edited out some of the spoilertags. It's possible to appreciate the thrust of your question without having any plot points spoiled.

Comment: Just because the Avalon didn't have hiberation tech doesn't mean that they never sent any to Homestead II on a cargo ship before hand.

Comment: [Exact duplicate on Movies.SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65797/12783). Vote for the [crossover questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/191265) feature request if you would like to have a single question be shareable on multiple sites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### There would be enough technology and expertise on Homestead II.

The same question was asked on [another SE site](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65797/27759) a few weeks ago, and the accepted answer there argues convincingly that **there may have been people asleep aboard the Avalon with the knowledge and tech necessary to put someone into hibernation**.

Recall how at one point in the movie Jim tries to find out about hibernation technology so that he can get his own pod working again, but the information was proprietary and he couldn't access it. Doubtless there were people on the ship who could - perhaps not Gus, but *somebody*. Or if not on the ship, then on Homestead II.

---

In the original screenplay (though not necessarily in the final movie, which ended up quite different), it was made clear that **there were already colonists on Homestead II before the arrival of the Avalon**:

> But in the script, the ship is actually landing on Homestead II, and we see the scene from the perspective of the colonists gathering to watch the new citizens arrive. The doors open and… Children of all ages and adults in smaller numbers exit.

So even if the technology required to put someone into hibernation didn't exist on board the Avalon, it might have been already existing on the destination planet.

Comment: I disagree with the first point. Since Jim and Aurora have access to the crew quarters but still have to remain awake, it stands to reason that no-one on the crew has the ability (either through lack of knowledge or lack of equipment) to put people into hibernation

Comment: @Valorum Does it? What if someone on the crew, with different skills or permissions from Gus, has the knowledge, but they have no way of finding out who?

Comment: Why wouldn't Gus have told them? Why wouldn't Gus simply wake up the Chief Medical Officer or the Captain if it was possible to return people to hibernation. Note also that with access to the Bridge and Crew Quarters, they could easily find a manifest with job titles.

Comment: They do seem to mention that there are people of all kinds of background. We know that the medical bay can mimic hybernation. We have the theoretical knowledge. We also have time i.e one year. So my guess is that some scientists and doctors can recreate the hybernation equipment by keeping the medical bay as a baseline and then following the manual to create the hybernation equipment.

Comment: @Valorum You're assuming that Gus would know who to wake up. The company seemed to be going to a lot of effort to keep their hibernation technology secret, which would probably extend to a 'need to know' policy even among their own employees. Also, Gus was pretty sick; maybe he simply wasn't thinking clearly? He was only around for, what, a few days before the end?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Gus has been around for 600 years and is a career starship crewman. The idea that he wouldn't know who to wake up to help them get back into hibernation seems vanishingly unlikely.

Comment: @Valorum Wait, what? 600 years? I must have missed that. I thought he was just an ordinary guy and low-ranking crewman. What sort of sci-fi is this?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - 600 years *subjective*. For the record he's a "Deck Chief". That seems moderately senior.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - From the original script -"JIM
But how long ago were you born?
GUS
Oh. Hang on...
(he does mental math)
About six hundred years ago.*

Comment: @Valorum You mean the script where they dumped all the other passengers out into space? That ain't canon, surely. (And yes, "Deck Chief" might be more senior than many of the crew on board, but it doesn't indicate any special level of access to things like hibernation technology.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Aside from some changes that were made to the end, the script is otherwise quite a reliable source of info about the film. As per usual, Hollywood decided that they needed a happily ever after instead of an ending that would have actually been good/dramatic/memorable.

Comment: @Valorum: As to why they didn't wake up the hibernation experts, it's possible that you need an awake person to put someone in hibernation (because it's not an automated process); therefore always leaving someone behind who cannot self-hibernate. And it seems counterproductive to sacrifice the life of a hibernation expert for that of a mechanic and (I forget what she was, but it's equally meaningless compared to being a hibernation expert)

Comment: @Flater - My instinct is that you need an entire facility to prep someone for hibernation. Undoubtedly such a thing would have been shipped out with the first colony ship to allow the crew to return to Earth. There wouldn't be a need for subsequent ships to carry one.

Comment: @Valorum: The med bay's capability of hibernating a single person seems to contradict the need for an entire facility. Unless it was specified that this is an "inferior" hibernation? (I don't remember that being mentioned)

Comment: @Flater - Jim mentions that it's not the same but that it'll do much the same job. One assumes that it's riskier/less efficient/more expensive or that there's some other reason it's not used as standard.

Answer (score 7):

The very short answer is that, at least according to the original script, Homestead II is already well under way in terms of colonisation efforts. The *earlier colonists* have built thriving cities with an eclectic mixture of frontier and modern technology.

> **VIDEO INSTRUCTOR:** *And none is more beautiful than Homestead II, the Jewel of the Occupied Worlds.*
>
> **ONE HOUR LATER -**   Jim sits wearily, chin propped on his hand. The Video Instructor chatters on. Inspiring footage of Homestead II.
>
> **VIDEO INSTRUCTOR:** *...thriving job markets in mining, farming and manufacturing. An explosion in the cultural arts. And if you long for
>   the life less civilized, you can apply for a pioneer permit and seek
>   your fortune in the wild.*

Jim's skills as a engineer will be put to good use and they likely have medical technology that rivals that of Earth. On top of that, as a Homestead colony they would have unfettered access to the "proprietary" technology that the Homestead company uses to put people into hibernation.

> **WORKSTATION:** *Hibernation technology is proprietary. The following articles deal with the subject on a theoretical level.*

---

As to the issue of whether someone on the crew can put people into hibernation,  since we know that the Jim and Aurora can't be returned to hibernation **despite finally gaining access to the crew** (with Gus's wristband and crew access codes) it stands to reason that no-one in the crew possesses the ability and/or the ship lacks the technology needed to put someone into hibernation without docking at a colony world.